# use the redundant values in SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have the following issue on SQL.

What I have (table A and table B)

[image]

What I want

[image]

My aim is to have a third table with the name of the file.

Info: my tables do not have any keys.

I've tried the code but it is not doing what I want

```
create table correspondance as 
   select b.var1, a.var1, a.var2 
   from A a 
   inner join B b on a.var1 = b.var2;
```

Any insights are welcomed.

**Edited**

I have this result :

```
var1       var2
azdt.csv   fich11.csv
zlata.csv  fich13.csv
```

Comment: what output do you get to the query you've written

Comment: If your table and column names haven't swapped around somewhere between the images and the query, should it not be `on a.var2 = b.var1` at the end?

Comment: Somesh, check my results on my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just joining on the wrong fields, and too many fields selected

```
select a.var1, b.var2 
   from A a 
   inner join B b on a.var2 = b.var1
```

Comment: Very weird. It is working actually , yet on my data , it is not working...Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense ... How come?

Comment: @AndyK Well, your sample data doesn't look coherent with your query and the result you get, so... hard to say. By the way, you didn't tell which dbms you're using.

Comment: SAS, Raphaël. In my case, things are not working when using my data but when dealing with my given example, well ...

Comment: I was checking my data. Could it be something with LF or space...? Need to check.

Comment: I'd figured out my issue. My initial change was dealt within SAS. I've tried again outside of SAS with a notepad, and miracle, the join is working fine.